# Print all the values from another class

Tags: c#

I have a project in which I need some help on how to create a print function that will show me all the vehicle details. Here is the code:

```
class Order
{
    // Variables
    private uint orderId;
    private string orderName;
    private bool orderComplete;
    private float orderCost;

    private JobDetails orderDetails;
    private Vehicle vehicleDetails;
    private WorkLog mechanicLog;

    // Properties
    public uint OrderId
    {
        get { return orderId; }
    }

    public string OrderName
    {
        get { return orderName; }
    }

    // Constructors
    public Order(string ordLine, string vehLine,string[] logLine)
    {
        orderDetails = new JobDetails(ordLine);
        creation code, ensure correct type is created
        
        vehicleDetails = new PersonalUseCars();
        mechanicLog = new WorkLog();

        for (int i = 0; i < logLine.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            mechanicLog.MakeNewEntry(logLine[i], logLine[i + 1]);
        }
        orderName = $"O_{vehicleDetails.Lplate}_{orderDetails.CustomerName}";
    }

    public Order(uint id)
    {
        orderId = id;
        orderDetails = new JobDetails();
        vehicleDetails = new Vehicle();
        mechanicLog = new WorkLog();
       matching data retrieval
        orderName = $"O{id}_{vehicleDetails.Lplate}_{orderDetails.CustomerName}";
    }

    // Methods
    public void DisplayAll()
    {
        orderDetails.Print();
        //TODO: Vehicle detail print
        mechanicLog.PrintLog();
    }

    public void ReturnAll(out string ord, out string veh, out List<Entry> log)
    {
        ord = orderDetails.SaveString();
        //TODO: Set veh to be equal to Vehicle output save string
        veh = vehicleDetails.returnString(); //Temp placeholder
        log = mechanicLog.ReturnLog();
    }

    public void DisplayOrd()
    {
        orderDetails.Print();
    }

    public void DisplayVeh()
    {
        //TODO: Call Vehicle print function
        DisplayAll();
    }

    public void DisplayLog()
    {
        mechanicLog.PrintLog();
    }

    public void AddToLog()
    {
        mechanicLog.MakeNewEntry();
    }
}
```

And here is the `Vehicle` class, in the TODOO comments I have to create a print function which later can be called and which will display information about a specific vehicle. Let me know if there is something wrong with the code.

```
class Vehicle
{
    public string Lplate { get; set; }
    public string Make;
    public string LMOT;
    public string Esize;
    public string Transmission;
    public string Mileage;
    public string FuleT;

    public Vehicle test(Vehicle ss)
    {
        Vehicle test = new Vehicle();
        test.Lplate = Lplate + ss.Lplate;
        return test;
    }
}

class PersonalUseCars : Vehicle
{
}

class BusinessCars : Vehicle
{
    public string CompanyN;
    public string CompanyA;
    public string FleetN;
}

class WorkVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public string CompanyN;
    public string CompanyA;
    public string purpose;
    public string Type;
}

class Motobikes : Vehicle
{
}
```

Comment: Create an object of said class, and print the members, or make a method that does that since they are private.

Comment: question unclear, is the "print vehicle" similar to `mechanic.PrintLog()`? what are you trying to do? do SecurityObscurity answer help? are you planning to print all info for `vehicle` including those inherit `vehicle`?

Comment: I would like to have a function that prints all the vehicle details including the inherent vehicle as well as a function which will display a specific vehicle for example Motobykes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to print every property the `Vehicle` and including all of its sub/child class, you will need reflection especially the `GetProperties()` method. You can do the following to get entire property of a given class instance:

```
 obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

The statement above will returns `PropertyInfo` which have two component that will be useful for our need, namely property `Name` and method called `GetValue`. The following is an example of using the reflection from inside the `Vehicle` class.

```
 using System;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class Vehicle
 {
   ....
   public string PrintVehicle()
   {
      List<string> lsProp = new List<string>();     
      foreach(PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        object propVal = prop.GetValue(this);
        if(propVal != null)
        {
           string propString = string.Format("{0} : {1}",
                       prop.Name, propVal.ToString());
           lsProp.Add(propString);
        }
      }
      return string.Join("\n", lsProp);
   }
   ....
 }
```

Note:

- There might be many caveats with reflection, so thread carefully. do test your code thoroughly afterward.
- It uses `ToString()` to convert non-string values, but do be aware non-simple types may return object name instead (e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` if its a `List` of `string`).
- You can use the method from another class, but you have to pass the `Vehicle` instance.
- You can use it to override `ToString()` too.
- If you dont want to use reflection, you could define the "printing" as virtual then override it on each subclasses, example:

  ```
     public class Vehicle
     {
         public string LPlate {get; set;}

         public virtual string PrintVehicle()
         {
             return "LPlate :" + LPlate;
         }
     }

     public class BusinessCar : Vehicle
     {
         public string CompanyN {get; set;}

         public override string PrintVehicle()
         {
             return base.PrintVehicle() + "\nCompanyN :" + CompanyN;
         }
     }

     public class Limousine : BusinessCar
     {
         public string Gadgets {get; set;}

         public override string PrintVehicle()
         {
             return base.PrintVehicle() + "\nGadgets :" + Gadgets;
         }
     }
  ```

Though the drawback is surely that you have to mention each property manually.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement a new print function for your classes like so:

```
///<summary>
///print the Vehicle details
///</summary>
public void print()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lplate: " + Lplate);
    Console.WriteLine("Make: " + Make);
    Console.WriteLine("LMOT: " + LMOT);
    Console.WriteLine("Esize: " + Esize);
    Console.WriteLine("Transmission: " + Transmission);
    Console.WriteLine("Mileage: " + Mileage);
    Console.WriteLine("FuleT: " + FuleT);
}
```

Or better yet you could override the toString() method

```
    ///<summary>
    ///toString() override
    ///</summary>
    ///<returns>string</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Lplate: " + Lplate + " Make: " + Make + " LMOT: " + LMOT + " Esize: " + Esize + " Transmission: " + Transmission + " Mileage: " + Mileage + " FuleT: " + FuleT;
    }
```